# python six library for 2 and 3 compatibility for requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, six

How can I use the python six library for 2 and 3 compatibility on the foll. code sample:

```
import urllib.request

wp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")
pw = wp.read()
print(pw)
```

-- EDIT I tried this:

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
import six.moves.urllib.request as Request

request = Request('http://google.com')
```

but get this error:

```
TypeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_request' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're looking for [this bit in the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost had it:

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

wp = urlopen("http://google.com")
pw = wp.read()
print(pw)
```

Or if you wanted to addess `urllib` directly as in the first attempt, use `from six.moves import urllib`.